# Java "Zero-Argument" Error

Tags: java, oop

I'm building a simulation game using Java. I have an interface, "Critter" and an abstract class "AbstractCritter". All of my "critters" are defined using these two.

Critter

```
public interface Critter {

        // create constants
        // each holds a unique integer value
        final int NORTH = 1;
        final int WEST = 2;
        final int SOUTH = 3;
        final int EAST = 4;
        final int CENTER = 5;

        // create abstract methods
        public char getChar();
        public int getMove(CritterInfo theInfo);                        
}
```

AbstractCritter

```
public abstract class AbstractCritter implements Critter{

    // create char to hold a particular critter
    private char critterChar;

    public AbstractCritter(final char theChar) {
        critterChar = theChar;
    }

    public char getChar() {
        return critterChar;
    }       
}
```

Example critter:

```
public class Stone extends AbstractCritter {

    public Stone(char S) {
        super(S);
        // This is the main constructor for stone
    }

    public int getMove(CritterInfo theInfo) {
        // The stone cannot move.
        return 5;
    }       
}
```

And the main loop:

```
public final class CritterMain {

  /** private constructor to inhibit instantiation. */
  private CritterMain() {
    // Do not instantiate objects of this class
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }

  /**
   * The start point for the CritterMain application.
   * 
   * @param theArgs command line arguments - ignored
   */
  public static void main(String[] theArgs) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        CritterFrame frame = new CritterFrame();

        frame.add(100, Stone.class);
        frame.add(50, Bat.class);
        frame.add(25, Frog.class);
        frame.add(25, Mouse.class);
        frame.add(25, Turtle.class);
        frame.add(25, Wolf.class);

        frame.start();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the main CritterMain, I get this weird error I can't find anywhere on google: "**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: no zero-argument constructor for class Stone**"

It has something to do with how I am defining my critters. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: The message seems fairly clear; you don't have a zero-argument constructor in your `Stone` class.

Comment: You can remove Critter and AbstractCritter from this post, because they don't influence the problem. Add the Stone class. Maybe you added a non zero-argument constructor and this is why your class doesn't have the default constructor ( zero-argument ).

Comment: Have you defined your `add` method in CritterFrame? If yes, post that code, please.

Comment: The CritterFrame, CritterMain are all tested and working. Eclipse is giving me an error when I try to add a zero-arg constructor like public Bat() {}.

Comment: I added an example critter "stone" which does not move. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace of the exception in your question.  Also, please show the code for the `add` method of the `CritterFrame` class.

Comment: Look int Java enums.  Numbers for "critter move" only become harder to use over time.  After all, you aren't checking your "critter move" for -1, -4, 12, MIN_INT, or MAX_INT, and rather than fixing it by checking for non-permitted return values, it's easier long term to just make it impossible to return those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make an instance of a class, you may use one of the available constructors.
A constructor may have no arguments, or more than zero arguments.

In case you don't declare a constructor with no argument and attempt to instantiate a class with no arguments, you obviously get an an error.

So just making a constructor with no arguments, will stop the error.

Comment: And will not work properly if it should always instantiate an object with an argument.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it by changing my stone class to :  private static final char S = 'S';

 public Stone() {
  super(S);
  // This is the main constructor for stone
 }